# Rails test Facebook methods using Koala and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, rspec, rspec-rails, koala

I'm making an application that uses Facebook info with Rails, Omniauth and Koala. 
Using [Ryan Bates Facebook Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api), I use this facebook method on my User model, to get the users uid, auth_token, etc from Facebook's API.

```
def facebook
  @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
end
```

I also have another method that calls the facebook method to get info from the user's friends, 
lets call this, `facebook_friends`

On my **UsersController** show action I have this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @friends = @user.facebook_friends
end
```

So I use those two instance variables in my show template.

**Writing tests with RSpec**

Here's one test I'm trying to make

```
feature 'As a logged out user' do
  background do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
  scenario 'redirects to root path' do
    visit user_path @user
    page.current_path.should == root_path
  end
end
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
1) As a logged out user redirects to root path
 Failure/Error: visit user_path @user
 Koala::Facebook::APIError:
   OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token.
 # ./app/models/user.rb:45:in `friends_birthday'
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `show'
 # ./spec/requests/user_integration_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Since I dont want to use a valid access token everytime I run the tests
**How can I fake the facebook call on the User model using RSpec?**

Comment: I don't know much about ruby... But I do know that you have to have a valid token in order to perform calls to the API on behalf of a user. There is no way around that - its part of Facebook's security measures.

Comment: Mock the request using e.g. webmock: https://github.com/bblimke/webmock

Comment: Any more info on how can I mock it? I can't find anything facebook related in the documentation

Answer (score 4):

VCR is the answer, you could check excelled railscasts about it http://railscasts.com/episodes/291-testing-with-vcr
Some examples you can find in my sample project: https://github.com/lucassus/locomotive/blob/master/spec/features/user_facebook_connect_spec.rb